# Concatenate characters according to a some number

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to write a SQL script that can concatenate a character like a comma according to a some number

Example

```
UPDATE Table1 
SET column1 = column1 + '.'
WHERE LEN(column1) = 2

UPDATE Table1 
SET column1 = column1 + '..'
WHERE LEN(column1) = 3

UPDATE Table1 
SET column1 = column1 + '...'
WHERE LEN(column1) = 4
```

I want to render this script automatic

Thanks.

Comment: Those are **dots** (`.`), not comma ( `,`) .... and the question is still confusing and unclear ......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this query adds 3 dots '.' to all values in column1, which have length = 3

```
declare @chr varchar(1) = '.'
declare @len int = 3

UPDATE Table1 
SET column1 = column1 + replicate(@chr, LEN(column1))
WHERE LEN(column1) = @len -- where clause is optional
```

without `where`, the query will update ALL rows and add `LEN(column1)` dots

Comment: thanks you very mutch M. ASh , i wanted to look a function like replicate

Answer (score 0):

this will generate you the updates

```
SELECT 
   'UPDATE Table1 SET column1 = column1 + ''' + REPLICATE('.', LEN(column1) -1) + ''' WHERE LEN(column1) = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, LEN(column1))
FROM 
   Table1
WHERE
   LEN(column1) > 1
GROUP BY LEN(column1)
```